# How to improve the delay in live auction (bidding) system

Tags: ruby-on-rails, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am currently trying to develop a live auction system and struggling to come up with the best approach to achieve it. The auction system needs to have the following features.

- the remaining seconds should be displayed and be synchronized on all participants’ devices.
- the remaining seconds should be incremented when bids are made. The incremented value changes based on the current remaining seconds (eg : increment 10 seconds if the current remaining seconds is less than 10 seconds, otherwise increment 30)
- auctions should end instantly when time is up

#### Below is the current approach.

1. Bidding request is made from client to Rails server to create bid data
2. `auction_end_at` value is incremented based on the remaining seconds and is posted to Firestore.
3. Client side then receives the incremented `auction_end_at` from Firestore and calculate the remaining seconds comparing with `new Date()` and displays it. This is done every second to execute the countdown.
4. The auction ends when the remaining seconds equals to zero and bidding buttons are hidden.

#### The problem with the approach.

Since there is a delay between creating a bidding request and client side receiving the incremented `auction_end_at`, the auction ends on client side (the client side countdown logic continues when processing the server side code and the remaining seconds becomes zero.) when people bid in the very last second.

#### Other approaches I have considered

- Remove Rails. By writing data from client side to Firestore directly should reduce the latency time. With this approach, the client side needs to have the incrementing the `auction_end_at` logic and does not seem like the best approach in terms of security reasons. (anyone can update the `auction_end_at` value)
- Using Cloud functions instead of Rails. Maybe faster than Rails?

I am stuck with this problem for a few days now, not being able to come up with the best approach. Any help would be very much appreciated. Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Hi, this is a very hard problem to crack on the client side and as per my understanding, you should not worry too much about the client side being active even if bidding has ended within few `ms` difference. your backend and more specifically the DB should have locking mechanism in place to avoid race condition and you are sorted for most of the scenarios. Also, Rails is not the problem here, delays are Inevitable, servers deployed nearby responds faster.

Comment: I wouldn't try to make it a milisecond-accurate at all. As mentioned above the locking system on the server side should do.

Comment: Hello! Thanks for the comments! Would you please explain more in details about the locking mechanism? How does it solve the situation where bids are actually created on server side but the auctions shown as finished on client side. (As mentioned in the question, this happens when people bid in the very last seconds)